# Draw drop shadow with semi-transparent view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIView which is semi-transparent. I want to add a drop shadow to it. The problem is that, the shadow opacity is low as well, because the view is semi-transparent. How can I make the shadow have full opacity?

Comment: You can do this by some trick but here the default behaviour is if parent view has low opacity so it will reflect to its child also.

Answer (score 0):

Place your view into a container view, and let the container view to drop the shadow.

Comment: Yes but than the container view needs to be transparent fully, which again wont work

Comment: Just make it a clear color, won't it work? Can you attach a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: How do you make your view semi-transparent? Do you just set the alpha to 0.5?

Comment: No, but by using [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.8];